# cant boot windows with ubuntu

Tags: windows

I installed Windows 10 in Legacy Mode because when in UEFI, it doesn't work.

Then I installed Ubuntu. It asked if I should Force UEFI Installation, I clicked go back and it installed.

I only saw Ubuntu after the installation:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options
System setup
```

When I click setup, it says:

`Error can't find command fwsetup press any key`

I can only boot Ubuntu in Legacy, nothing works in UEFI.

I can see my 300 GB Windows drive

Gparted shows:

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 628 GB -- Here probably Ubuntu
/dev/sda2 extended 28 GB
/devsda5 linuxswap 28 GB
/dev/sda3 NTFS 500 mb 
/dev/sda4 ntfs 280 GB win10
Unallocated 2 MB
```

Where did i do wrong? Should I first install Ubuntu? Windows throws an error `cant convert gpt` while installing Windows.

Comment: What is your motherboard model? It could not be UEFI.

Comment: Windows only installs in UEFI mode in GTP drives; for Legacy it requires MBR. There's no way around it. Ubuntu,on the other hand, is less picky as it can be installed Legacy in a GTP drive with only the addition of a bios_grub partition in the beginning of the drive. Whenever possible, if the hardware is UEFI enabled, use GTP and always install in UEFI mode. If your Windows installation media (USB recommended) doesn't work in UEFI mode then you did something wrong and that something is off-topic here, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your terminal and type
`sudo update-grub`

After that restart your computer.

Hopefully, you'll get the Windows on the menu and it'll work fine.